# Power BI 100% stacked area chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Hi I am wanting to get the same effect as the '100% stacked column chart' but using an area chart visual. I think the best way would be to create a measure. So far I have created a measure for the percentage

Percentage = COUNT(Locations[Latest Rating]) / CALCULATE(COUNT(Locations[Latest Rating]), ALLSELECTED(Locations))

And get the values:
[image]

However want the % out of 100. So for example "Good = 1.30%" I know the calculation should be 1.30/1.91 *100 so should be 68%. Not sure the best way to calculate this. Using a legend on the visual also.

Comment: creating measures for percentages that will effectively make the stacked area chart into a 100% is the solution for your case and your logic for converting values considering 100% seems ok to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DAX and the Stacked Area Chart to produce a visual totalling 100%

With a starting point of the following data

[image: Quality Level Source Data]

Use DAX to calculate the daily quality rating percentage, by dividing the value by the sum of ratings across all Quality Levels (Good, Outstanding etc)

```
Quality Rating Percentage = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM(Locations[Rating]),
    CALCULATE(
        sum(Locations[Rating]),
        ALL(Locations[Quality Level])
    )
 )
```

Add the stacked area chart to view the daily change of quality with like

[image: Stacked Area Chart to 100%]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, the legend I am using which you have called "Quality level" is actually the same "Rating" from the measure. So It is a percentage broken down by the 4 "Ratings" categories which I am wanting a 100% stacked area chart.

Comment: Hi, I might be missing the point, in which case I'll remove the answer, but to explain the steps I've added the source data in.  The DAX calc takes the source data and effectively converts to a percentage by the Ratings (Quality Level) per day.  Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Looking at one column "Latest Rating" which has the four values 'Outstanding','Good','Requires Improvement','Inadequate'. I am wanting to calculate the % of each per month out of 100% like a stacked column chart.

So for example there are many organisations that give a rating each month, I am wanting to see the different between the ratings broken down by month. So everything is coming from this one column "Latest rating" I'm just stuck on how to get the out of 100% calculation from the values I have got from my original post.

Hope this makes sense?

Thank you

Comment: The percentage is coming from the values from the "Latest Rating" column as they are text values I did this through a count. So the rating is not a separate integer column.

Comment: The DAX expression will give you latest rating as a percentage calculated over the period you place on the X Axis.  For example, the calculation for Good on the second date is (1.8 / 2.65) *100 resulting in 67.92%, therefore working out the percentage of Good for a period.  I have placed day on the X axis, but you could use month, quarter, year etc on the X Axis and the expression will summarise accordingly.  Try using the above DAX expression (replaced with your field names) and drop on a stacked chart and I think you will get what you are looking for